# According to Young Earth Creationism, how did carnivores come into existence?

Tags: genesis, creation, young-earth-creation, fall-of-man, animals

According to Young Earth Creationism, were all animals vegetarian/vegan before the fall? If so, how did carnivores come into existence? Did carnivores evolve from vegetarian ancestors? Were carnivores created by God after the fall? Were carnivores the result of genetic manipulation performed by fallen angels after the fall?

Comment: We don't close questions just because they're really basic and easily answered, but we do discourage them. This is a question that should be really easy to find an answer at any of the major creationist websites. Have you had difficulty navigating those sites?

Comment: Maybe this is too wide of a question?  For instance, if we didn't start out with carnivores, the reproductive rates of prey items must have radically changed as well.

Comment: @MikeBorden, not necessarily; animals can adjust their reproductive rates according to environmental pressures. In the beginning, animals were commanded to "be fruitful and multiply" (Genesis 1:22), so even before carnivores, there's a good argument to be made for animals being *capable* of rapid reproduction. If they were *also* designed to slow that rate as they approach the limits of sustainability, carnivores may not have been necessary.

Comment: On the subject of being easy to find an answer elsewhere, https://www.icr.org/article/did-lions-roam-garden-eden covers most of the questions asked...

Comment: @Matthew When the fox population is low mice don't stop having upwards of 10 litters of 5 or six per year.  As the limits of sustainability are approached breeding may lessen but that is a high mouse density.  It is the overabundance of mice (fox food) that helps the fox population rebound.  If nothing was eating mice at the beginning, either their reproduction was vastly different or there was an infestation in Eden pretty quickly.

Comment: @MikeBorden, what would constitute "an infestation" prior to the Fall/Curse? Why would having lots of mice be an issue? That said, it's certainly possible that fast breeding is an adaptation to predation; if nothing is eating you and your offspring aren't dying in droves due to disease, accidents and whatnot (as all would have been the case in Eden), there is less *need* to reproduce quickly. (Alternatively, they might have just spread out a lot more, per the command to "*fill* the Earth", which requires not staying in one place. See also Babel.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> were all animals vegetarian/vegan before the fall?

Yes; they were created this way (Genesis 1:30), and will be this way again in the New Creation (Isaiah 65:17-25).

> Did carnivores evolve from vegetarian ancestors?

Be careful with the word "evolve". Evolutionism is an anti-theistic fallacy that has never been demonstrated and the only "evidence" for it is a bunch of assertions founded in the dogma that God doesn't exist.

One possibility is that carnivores arose from herbivores via the process of *natural selection* (which *has* been observed and is accepted by YECs), which is the process of species changing their attributes ***within*** the available genetic diversity of their Kind. This diversity was *already present* at Creation; God, in his wisdom and foreknowledge, would have allowed for carnivory from the start and provided certain animals with the genetic potential. Indeed, *all* animals (AFAIK) can eat meat (yes, even ruminants!), and will do so if it is available, but some are better adapted to obtaining it than others.

Another possibility is that some animals were changed by God as part of the Curse. One possible evidence in support of this is the apparent change to "the serpent"; Genesis 3:14 suggests that God may have immediately altered the anatomy of "the serpent", in which case, perhaps other changes were made at the same time. However, even if this occurred, additional changes as discussed in the previous paragraph may have also occurred.

p.s. Naturalists believe — contrary to the laws of thermodynamics and information theory, because they have no other choice that does not invalidate their religion — that such information can spontaneously come into existence via "random mutations". There are significant problems with this conjecture, but the only alternative is Intelligent Design, which is anathema to Naturalists.

p.p.s. Yes, I used the R-word. Naturalism is a religion (or philosophy, if you prefer, but the difference between religion and philosophy is pedantic at best) whose unassailable dogma is "there is no God". Evolutionism is a necessary result of Naturalism, although some Christians have been duped into also accepting it through various social pressures.

> Were carnivores created by God after the fall?

No. On the seventh day, God rested from his work of Creation (Genesis 2:2). God's work of Creation was completed at the end of the sixth day.

> Were carnivores the result of genetic manipulation performed by fallen angels after the fall?

I am not aware of any evidence for this hypothesis, not of any significant groups that believe this. OTOH, I don't offhand feel entirely confident in categorically ruling it out. My personal belief is "no", that carnivores arose via natural selection, but I can't "prove" it.

I should also add that there are various records of cats — supposedly obligate carnivores — thriving on a vegan diet, in accordance with Isaiah 65:25. This would seem to support that even cats were, at some point, herbivores.

---

Further reading:

- https://www.icr.org/article/did-lions-roam-garden-eden
- https://answersingenesis.org/animal-behavior/what-animals-eat/creations-original-diet-and-the-changes-at-the-fall/
- https://answersingenesis.org/animal-behavior/what-animals-eat/unexpectedly-vegetarian-animals-what-does-it-mean/

Comment: Thorns were introduced after the fall, so it's possible animal diets were too. On the other hand creationists have identified a lot of normally carnivorous species that have occasionally vegetarian individuals, so a sudden change by God after the fall probably wasn't necessary.

Comment: Indeed  Whitetail Deer have been seen eating injured birds, fish, and other carrion from time to time so the non-conformity goes both ways.